# Discord money bot keeping user ID's in json file. When Bot restarts it creats a new (but same) ID for everyone

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py

When this code runs it works getting the user ID from discord and putting they have 100 money in the json, but once you restart the bot you have to register again and it writes the same user ID in the json file thinking it's a new user when it is not.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import json

bot = commands.Bot('!')

amounts = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global amounts
    try:
        with open('amounts.json') as f:
            amounts = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load amounts.json")
        amounts = {}

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def balance(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    if id in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You have {} in the bank".format(amounts[id]))
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 100
        await ctx.send("You are now registered")
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You already have an account")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def transfer(ctx, amount: int, other: discord.Member):
    primary_id = ctx.message.author.id
    other_id = other.id
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account")
    elif other_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("The other party does not have an account")
    elif amounts[primary_id] < amount:
        await ctx.send("You cannot afford this transaction")
    else:
        amounts[primary_id] -= amount
        amounts[other_id] += amount
        await ctx.send("Transaction complete")
    _save()

def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)

@bot.command()
async def save():
    _save()

bot.run("Token")
```

JSON after the bot is turned off and back on and registered twice (fake user IDs):

```
{"56789045678956789": 100, "56789045678956789": 100}
```

Need it to be able to recognize the user IDs even after the bot is turned off and back on.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in dictionaries, and the keys of the dictionary should be showing up as integers, because you're using the rewrite branch.  Can you double check and confirm that you're seeing these duplicate string keys?

Comment: Yes they are 100% the same keys. PyCharm is warning me that the two keys are duplicates. To make some clarifications this happens when the bot is on, a user does '!register' then the bot is stopped and restarted and the user does '!register' again. The user must do !register again because it thinks it has not registers the user yet causing the duplicate keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because JSON objects always have strings for the "keys".  So `json.dump` converts the integer keys to strings.  You can do the same by converting the user ids to strings before you use them.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import json

bot = commands.Bot('!')

amounts = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global amounts
    try:
        with open('amounts.json') as f:
            amounts = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load amounts.json")
        amounts = {}

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def balance(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You have {} in the bank".format(amounts[id]))
    else:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 100
        await ctx.send("You are now registered")
        _save()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You already have an account")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def transfer(ctx, amount: int, other: discord.Member):
    primary_id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    other_id = str(other.id)
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("You do not have an account")
    elif other_id not in amounts:
        await ctx.send("The other party does not have an account")
    elif amounts[primary_id] < amount:
        await ctx.send("You cannot afford this transaction")
    else:
        amounts[primary_id] -= amount
        amounts[other_id] += amount
        await ctx.send("Transaction complete")
    _save()

def _save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)

@bot.command()
async def save():
    _save()

bot.run("Token")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to load the .json file that you have created at program startup. Instead of `amounts = {}` try this:

```
import os

if os.path.exists('amounts.json'):
    with open('amounts.json', 'r') as file:
        amounts = json.load(file)
else:
    amounts = {} # default to not loading if file not found
```

## UPDATE

I believe after reading your comment and reviewing your code the issue is in your `register()` code.

You have:

```
if id not in amounts:
```

But it should be:

```
if id not in amounts.keys():
```

Comment: @PatrickHaugh You're right it is basically the same. I wouldn't know what else would cause it to reset every time the bot is loaded though. I figure it is worth a shot, perhaps the `on_ready` event is not being called or something and this would help diagnose that if this fixed it.

Comment: After trying this it does the same thing as before creating duplicate keys in the JSON file

Comment: Regarding your edit, membership tests on dictionaries only look at they keys.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh could you elaborate on what you mean by that? I've always used `.keys()` to generate lists of keys for comparison. Are you saying that isn't necessary and is done implicitly?

Comment: `if item in dictionary` test whether `item` is a key in the dictionary, and when you iterate over a dictionary you iterate over they keys.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh That makes sense, but if there is not a significant speed improvement I don't see why not explicitly use `.keys()`, `.values()`, or `.items()` to make code more readable. I guess semantics wouldn't solve OP's problem though

Answer (score -1):

I found out the problem and tested it myself, so it isn't the .keys() or the os thing, but in the _save() function. I first did a test with the _save function and without it, and instead of using a called on function, it worked when i did it manually. Like so

(P.S i did this within a cog, only difference is the name @commands.command, which is @bot.command and you need to add "self")

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(self, ctx):
    id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
    with open("smth.json") as json_file:
        amounts = json.load(json_file)
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 0
        await ctx.send("You are now registered")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You already have an account!")
    with open("smth.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(amounts, outfile)
```

ALSO VERY IMPORTANT NOTE, make sure when you create a json file, it's name ends with ".json" and all that's in it is

```
{

}
```