# Discord.py Currency system

Tags: discord.py

How do you make the discord bot have custum currency and the more they talk the more XP they get? A command is they can check their balance`/balance`. . An admin can check anyones amount `/amount [@user]`, give `/give [@user] [amount]` or take `/take [@user] [amount]`. I would like to save this all in a JSON file called amounts.json. Sorry if that is a lot of commands and work. THANKS!

Comment: This is probably a decent place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485988/discord-money-bot-keeping-user-ids-in-json-file-when-bot-restarts-it-creats-a

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic template for a currency system that saves the data to a JSON file. It also loads the data from the JSON file each time the script is run. It's not refined at all, and won't look great for the user, but it's just a basic template.

```
import discord
import json

with open("amounts.json") as file:
    xp = json.loads(file.read())

def save_to_json():
    with open("amounts.json", "w") as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(xp))

class Client(discord.Client):
    @staticmethod
    async def on_message(message):
        xp[str(message.author.id)] += 1

        if message.content == "/balance":
            await message.reply(f"Your balance is {xp[str(message.author.id)]}")
        elif message.content.startswith("/amount "):
            target_user = message.content[8:].strip(" @<!")
            await message.reply(f"That user's balance is {xp[target_user]}")
        elif message.content.startswith("/give "):
            target_user = message.content[8:message.content.find(" ", 9)].strip(" @<!")
            give_amount = int(message.content[message.content.find(" ", 9) + 1:])
            xp[target_user] += give_amount
            save_to_json()
            await message.reply("XP was given successfully")
        elif message.content.startswith("/take "):
            target_user = message.content[8:message.content.find(" ", 9)].strip(" @<!")
            take_amount = int(message.content[message.content.find(" ", 9) + 1:])
            xp[target_user] -= take_amount
            save_to_json()
            await message.reply("XP was taken successfully")

client = Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
client.run(TOKEN)
```